# Is there a way to achieve this notation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

[image: Tensor Multiplication on Multiple lines]

I'm trying to achieve this notation from overleaf. I would appreciate some direction. I tried `C3 \choose C2 \choose C1` to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\choose` is for binomial coefficients and only takes two entries use `pmatrix` environment here

Comment: As David mentions this is just four uses of the `pmatrix` env (this is just single column matrices). Matricies should be covered in any decent introduction to LaTeX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As David Carlisle and @daleif have already pointed out, a LaTeX-based solution could be based on loading the `amsmath` package and employing its `pmatrix` ("parenthetic matrix") environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\newcommand\myvec[1]{\begin{pmatrix} #1_3 \\ #1_2 \\ #1_1 \end{pmatrix}}
\begin{document}
\[
\myvec{\mathbf{C}} = \myvec{\mathbf{A}} \otimes \myvec{\mathbf{B}} =
\begin{pmatrix} 
  \mathbf{A}_3 \times \mathbf{B}_3 \\ 
  \mathbf{A}_2 \times \mathbf{B}_2 \\ 
  \mathbf{A}_1 \times \mathbf{B}_1 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a TABstack alternative to the standard `amsmath` way involving the `pmatrix` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
\parenVectorstack{\mathbf{C}_3\\\mathbf{C}_2\\\mathbf{C}_1}
=
\parenVectorstack{\mathbf{A}_3\\\mathbf{A}_2\\\mathbf{A}_1}
\otimes
\parenVectorstack{\mathbf{B}_3\\\mathbf{B}_2\\\mathbf{B}_1}
=
\parenVectorstack{\mathbf{A}_3\times\mathbf{B}_3\\
                  \mathbf{A}_2\times\mathbf{B}_2\\
                  \mathbf{A}_1\times\mathbf{B}_1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Brain burp.  Just changed it.  I guess I was thinking that `\mathbf` would retain italic.

Comment: Is there any advantage of tabstack over pmatrix and friends?

Comment: @Aditya specifying row baselineskip for aesthetic reasons is trivial.  In tabbed matrices, the column separation is equally adjustable.  Tabbed matrices also allow a mode in which all columns are forced to equal width, desirable in some situations. These can also, in some more complex `aligned`-like situations, allow nice flexibility in preference to strictly-`&`-based approaches.  The downside is that tags cannot be applied to rows, so that only a single equation number may be applied.

Answer (score 3):

[image: img]

```
\begin{pmatrix}
C_3 \\ C_2 \\ C_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
A_3 \\ A_2 \\ A_1
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
B_3 \\ B_2 \\ B_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
A_3 \times B_3 \\ A_2 \times B_2 \\ A_1 \times B_1
\end{pmatrix}
```

https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php